# What is the "fourth" Haar basis function of the 4×4 Haar basis?

Tags: wavelets

I know the three Haar basis functions

```
//mother wavelet:
[1 1 -1 -1]
//dilation:
[1 -1 0 0] 
//translation:
[0 0 1 -1]
```

However, the Haar basis consists of four basis elements:
The mother wavelet, the translation, the dilation and another, fourth element, which I don't understand. According to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_wavelet), this fourth element is

```
[1 1 1 1]
```

But how would this one look like, and how is it obtained (dilation/translation, whatever combination)? This confuses me.

Btw: is the Haar basis defined as

```
[ 1  1  1  1
  1  1 -1 -1
  1 -1  0  0
  0  0  1 -1]
```

or as the transpose of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the notation right, it looks like the [1 1 1 1] element is just the [DC coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_coefficient), i.e. the mean of the input signal.

By symmetry, the Haar wavelet integrates to 0 over its domain.  Thus, if you didn't include the DC coefficient, adding a constant bias to the input signal would not change its Haar transform at all.

Comment: This has been very helpful, thanks! Say, I want to apply H_4 (as given above) to a signal x, do I use the matrix I gave above or its transpose? Just to be clear of the definition.

Comment: @ptikobj: That surely depends on whether you're using row or column vectors to represent your data.  (If you're using column vectors, I assume you should use the matrix as given.  If you're using row vectors, use the transpose.)